# Rotating SceneKit Cylinder Around A Single Axis

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have the following code to enable the display of a 3D cylinder within a view.  When viewing it on the device, gestures rotate the cylinder on both the x-axis (swipe up and down gesture) and y axis (swipe left and right), but the z axis is locked.  This, I believe is the default for allowsCameraControl.

What I would like to do is lock the x-axis (I think) so that only left and right swipe gestures work.  I shouldn't be able to see the top or the bottom of the cylinder. I would like to keep the default rotation whilst swiping left and right (i.e. it naturally slows down after swipe).

Any help gratefully received!

```
class MyCollectionViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scnView: SCNView!

var scnScene: SCNScene!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sceneSetup()
}


// MARK: Scene
func sceneSetup() {

    scnScene = SCNScene()

    let cylinder = SCNNode(geometry: SCNCylinder(radius: 5.0, height: 20))
    cylinder.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "image1")
    cylinder.geometry?.firstMaterial?.specular.contents = UIColor.white

    scnView.allowsCameraControl = true

    scnScene.rootNode.addChildNode(cylinder)

    scnView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true

    scnView.scene = scnScene
}
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the following to your code can lock the vertical

```
   scnView.defaultCameraController.maximumVerticalAngle = 0.001
```

Comment: Love a one line solution!  Thanks!